# array_slice() for large array, good or bad

Tags: php, arrays, slice

In PHP, does `array_slice()` serve good enough to process large data `array` that cannot be `paginated` since its not stored in `database` but calculated on other `db tables`.

Anyways, so I have an `array` of around `50k` which might **increase** later. First time on page load it **fetches all 50k records** then `slices` it for `ajax based pagination`.
Will this cause **`server load`** in future since all `records` are being fetched on **page load**?

Comment: Limit the data in sql before going to query it in your server. For example `Select * from data Limit 10`

Comment: What aldrin said, why on earth would you create a 50k array when you can just bring what you need from the DB directly?

Answer (score 0):

At first its a bad idea to create array containing 50K moreover it can encrease. It may "eat" all your memory in high traffic. 
Also where you store sliced parts of array for using on ajax requests?

I think (if you can not set limit in query) you can create **additional table** in which you can store your data (with cron for example) and show users data from it using limit for pagination, or you can create **caching layer** (or use existed caching systems: file cache, php memcache, ...), and write some algorithm for updating cache (it depends on your programm logic).

Comment: well I talked to the client they say it won't be 50k but around 15-20k. Right now im storing the array in Session firing ajax pagination on it. And clearing that session variable in header if other pages are opened. I know its not a good practice but its what I can think of right now. Please let me know if you can tell me is .json files are storing instead of session.

Comment: @Cinderghoul It is very bed to store data, especially big data (which not associated with authentification or some settings) in session. You can take data from different tables, end than store it in cache files (f.e in JSON files as you say). Take data, slice it to parts and each part store in json (f.e. datapart1, datapart2, ...) and on first  page load first part, on second page datapart2 and so on. If your data updates for example one time in date you can delete and recreate that jsons one time in date.

Comment: I'm using Laravel's Cache system to store this data now.

Comment: @Cinderghoul It's good that you use cache system. You can update cache on some events (f.e. if something updated in database), or once a day instead of deleting it after user session end